# assembly: subtract signed words

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote this code to solve an equation. It works good for addition and multiplication but for the subtraction it is not giving the correct result.

```
;to subtract 
mov ax,00
mov bx,00 
mov dx,00
mov cx,00
mov si,offset mulx
mov di,offset sumy
mov bx,offset subr 
mov ax,word ptr [si]
cwd
sub ax,word ptr[di]
mov word ptr[bx],ax  
add si,2
add di,2
add bx,2 
mov dx,word ptr [si]
cwd
sub dx,word ptr[di]
mov word ptr[bx],dx

HLT
```

The equation is: `sum(X)*m - sum(y) / n`
All are signed numbers, `x` is byte and `y` is word, `m` and `n` are also words. The problem is with subtraction, how can i solve it ??

Comment: _not giving the correct result_ is a bad problem description. Tell us what input you provided, what output you got and what you expected. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Where are the `x` and `y` and `n` you mention, in your code? Please be explicit about the number of bits you are adding, **and** resulting in. `CWD` converts `AX` to 32 bits (extended to `DX`). Yet you never use`DX` before you issue *another* `CWD` instruction.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood `CWD`.

Answer (score 1):

with your 2nd `CWD` instruction, you are wiping out the value of `DX` before you even use it. look up what `CWD` does.

you probably shouldn't even be using `CWD` at all. if you are subtracting one doubleword from another, load both halves of the word first into `AX` and `DX`, then subtract, using `SBB` with `DX`:

```
  mov ax, word [si]
  mov dx, word [si+2]
  sub ax, word [di]
  sbb dx, word [di+2]
  mov word [bx], ax  
  mov word [bx+2], dx
```